# Is there a default password for the UBUNTU bootable stick?

Tags: password, default

Good day...
I made a bootable USB stick, with UBUNTU 12.04 desktop (and on my laptop).
(It does not work with my desktop... the monitor goes to stand by).
I was successful at getting UBUNTU to boot.
After using it for a while I was also successful at getting the computer to restart and then made a second stick.
I managed to boot to UBUNTU again and used it for a while.
Then I made the mistake of logging off before shutting the computer down.  Doing so took me to the logon page.  When I tried to shut the computer down from there, nothing happened.  I tried several times but it would not shut down.  I also tried restart several times and it would not do that either.
I do not know whether that is the way it is designed, or if that's a new bug.
And what I tried to log back on I get an... incorrect password error message.

Is there a default password for the UBUNTU bootable stick?

The directions on how to make the stick do not include anything about a default password.
Nor do they warn to create a password before doing anything else, so you don't get stuck.
The only two options are for it to be in hibernation or for the logon page to be displayed.
I can find no way to get back to the boot selection menu.  Which means I do not even have any way of reinstalling an operating system.
I hope someone can help... have a nice day... John
PS, on looking through the FAQs again to see if I might of missed something before, it looks like it may be suspended it rather than hibernating but the result is the same I can't do anything.  Also it did not have me provide it with the user name or password during the construction process.

Comment: The default user-name is `ubuntu` and empty password. do check the [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of Ubuntu ISO image .

Comment: @tijybba Why don't you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Referring through this [LiveCd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) page it suggests the **default User available** is **`ubuntu`** and **Blank/Empty password** , just press Enter on Password prompt for logging in.

Comment: @John Biberstein - Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, please comment or clarify for further required info.

Comment: THANK YOU... sorry it has taken so long for me to get back to this.  The software was complaining about the password, however the actual problem was I was not using ubuntu as the username.  Then I managed to install wine.  But some of the programs that I use most don't seem to work with wine.  So I'm probably stuck with Windows anyway.... John  @tijybba

Comment: @JohnBiberstein - if you are keen towards Ubuntu , then there might be alternatives to the Programs you use , do refer this site by searching , if not found , you are free to ask :)